# Excel - Finding point location of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel 2013, I am programmatically adding a chart.  To do so, I need to specify WHERE the chart is located.  Specifically top, left, height and width.  All these coordinates are points, not cell addresses.  For example, the default height of a cell if 15 points.  I know the cell address where I want the Graph to be located.  How do I convert a cell address to a point? There has to be a better way than just iterating through every previous row/column and adding their height/width...

For example, Cell 'F7' might be 120 points left, and have a top point location of 90.

If it helps any, the syntax to add the chart is...

```
expression.AddChart2(Style,XlChartType,Left,Top,Width,Height,NewLayout)
```

Comment: You want the chart to span the full width of the screen?

Comment: No,  Width would be reasonably static based on the type of data I am charting.  I am more concerned about Left and Top.  For example, I might want the chart to be to the right of a Pivot Table.  I know the Pivot table goes from Column 'A' to column 'L'.  I want the Chart to start at Column L + one empty column, so starting at column 'N', specifically 'N4'.  How do I convert N4 to Left and Top points?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
    X = Range("N4").Left
    Y = Range("N4").Top
```

I don't have anything to test it on so not sure it works.